# Creating Contract Gas Problem

Tags: remix, gas, oracles, gas-limit

When I create my contract on remix using metamask (injected web3) it asks me to lower my gas fee. Once I lower it (if I don't I can't create it) the contract gets created BUT my variables inside the contract are not initialized. For example a var a = 10; is returning 0. 
When I comment out some oraclize functions and lower the gas need then my contract deploys fine. I have no idea what's going on.

I added the code and a screenshot. As I said. Once I started commenting out 'oraclize' function at some point it starts to work just fine...

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;
import "./oraclize.sol";

contract Casino is usingOraclize {
   address owner;
   uint public betAmount = 30 finney; //Equal to 0.01 Ether
   uint public totalBet; //Amount of Ether bet for current game
   uint public numberOfBets; //Total number of current bets
   //uint public maxAmountOfBets = 1 //Maximum amount of bets can be made for each game by each user
   uint public limitAmountOfBets = 3; //Maximum amount of bets for each game
   uint public numberWinner; //Number that won last game
   address[] public players; //Players
   mapping(uint => address[]) numberBetPlayers; //Who bet for which number
   mapping(address => uint) playerBetsNumber; //Number bet by each player

   modifier onEndGame() {
       if(numberOfBets >= limitAmountOfBets) _;
   }

   //constructor - set bet amount and max bets in each game
   function Casino(uint _betAmount, uint _limitAmountOfBets) {
       owner = msg.sender; //set creator of contract to owner

       if(_betAmount > 0) betAmount = _betAmount;
       if(_limitAmountOfBets > 0) limitAmountOfBets = _limitAmountOfBets;

       oraclize_setProof(proofType_Ledger); //arge
   }

   //check if player exists in current game
   function checkPlayerExists(address player) public returns(bool) {
       if(playerBetsNumber[player] > 0) return true;
       else return false;
   }

   //bet function
   function bet(uint numberToBet) payable {
       require(numberOfBets <= limitAmountOfBets); //check if limit has been reached
       require(!checkPlayerExists(msg.sender)); //check that player hasn't bet before
       require(numberToBet >=1 && numberToBet <= 10); //check that the bet is between 1 and 10
       require(msg.value == betAmount); //check that ether send by sender is equal to bet amount

       playerBetsNumber[msg.sender] = numberToBet;
       numberBetPlayers[numberToBet].push(msg.sender);

       numberOfBets += 1;
       totalBet += msg.value;

       if(numberOfBets >= limitAmountOfBets) generateNumberWinner();
   }

   //generate random numbers using oraclize_newRandomDSQuery function
   function generateNumberWinner() payable onEndGame {
       uint numberRandomBytes = 4;
       uint delay = 0;
       uint callbackGas = 200000;

       bytes32 queryId = oraclize_newRandomDSQuery(delay, numberRandomBytes, callbackGas);
   }

   function __calback(bytes32 _queryId, string _result, bytes _proof) oraclize_randomDS_proofVerify(_queryId, _result, _proof) onEndGame {
       assert(msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());

       numberWinner = (uint(sha3(_result))%10+1);
       distributePrizes();
   }

   function distributePrizes() onEndGame {
       uint winnerEtherAmount = totalBet / numberBetPlayers[numberWinner].length; //how much each winner will get

       for(uint i = 0; i < numberBetPlayers[numberWinner].length; i++) { //sent ether to addresses
           numberBetPlayers[numberWinner][i].transfer(winnerEtherAmount);
       }

       for(uint j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
           numberBetPlayers[j].length = 0;
       }

       totalBet = 0;
       numberOfBets = 0;
   }
}
```

[image: Gas limit problem?]

Any help??
Thanks.

Comment: Hi there. Could you include your contract code?

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be your contract requires more gas than default gas. Try to increases gas value in remix.

A brief about Gas and gasPrice.:

Gas is a fixed unit for each step, this is defined in EVM level.

gasPrice is decided my miners, for executing each step how many ether willing to spend.

Comment: I increased the gas value but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: Add 4469391 as a gas

Comment: Yes it did work BUT how did you come up with this number and why has it to be EXACTLY this number and not any larger number like 4700000. Can you please explain so I can understand it more clearly? Thanks!

Comment: Really looking forward to your solution? I try same gas with same code but now I get same error again... :(

Answer (score 0):

Optimize option set to true in remix solved the problem. For now at least.